# ubuntu does not boot up

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2, bootloader

I have a computer with ubuntu 14 and windows 10.  I logged on windows, restarted the computer but the grub boot loader did not come up. I have tried pressing Shift upon bootup but no boot options show up either.  I have tried booting the computer while the flash drive which has ubuntu on it but that has not worked.  Besides trying with a bootable cd/dvd, is there anything else i can try to fix this installation?

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't see the bootloader, it means that it is not installed, at least not properly, or it was overwritten.

I would recommend you to boot from a live-cd/usb and try boot-repair:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Good luck

Comment: that is what i am trying.  bootloader was installed previously - I have been using the computer for a few months and have rebooted multiple times in the past successfully...till now